# Сохранение данных в Realm

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

Начал осваивать Realm и столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Запрашиваю данные и сохраняю их, а потом пытаюсь их отобразить.  Не получается правильно сохранить массив данных в БД, чтобы в дальнейшем из него брать данные для отображения.
Полностью страница кода выглядит следующим образом:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var request: Disposable? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Realm.init(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val o = createRequest().map { Gson().fromJson(it, FeedAPI::class.java) }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        request = o.subscribe({
            val feed = Feed(
                it.top.mapTo(
                    RealmList<FeedItem>(),
                    { feed -> FeedItem(feed.game, feed.channels, feed.viewers) })
            )
            Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransaction { realm ->

                val oldList = realm.where(Feed::class.java).findAll()
                if (oldList.size > 0)
                    for (item in oldList)
                        item.deleteFromRealm()

                realm.copyToRealm(feed)
            }
            showNewsRecView()
            for (item in it.top)
                Log.d(
                    "M_MainActivity",
                    "game= ${item.game.name} " + "logo = ${item.game.logo.large}" + "channels = ${item.channels} " + "viewers = ${item.viewers} "
                )
        }, {
            Log.d("M_MainActivity", "", it)
            showNewsRecView()
        })
    }
    fun showNewsRecView() {
        Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransaction { realm ->
            val feed = realm.where(Feed::class.java).findAll()
            if (feed.size > 0) {
                act1_recView.adapter = RecAdapter(feed[0]!!.top)
                act1_recView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            }
        }

    }
}

class FeedAPI(
    val top: ArrayList<FeedItemAPI>
)

class FeedItemAPI(
    val game: FeedGameAPI,
    val channels: String,
    val viewers: String
)

class FeedGameAPI(
    val name: String,
    val logo: FeedLogoAPI
)

class FeedLogoAPI(
    val large: String
)

open class Feed(
    var top: RealmList<FeedItem> = RealmList<FeedItem>()
) : RealmObject()

open class FeedItem(
    var game: FeedGame? = null,
    var channels: String = "",
    var viewers: String = ""
) : RealmObject()

open class FeedGame(
    var name: String = "",
    var logo: FeedLogo? = null
) : RealmObject()

open class FeedLogo(
    var large: String = ""
) : RealmObject()

class RecAdapter(private val top: RealmList<FeedItem>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false)
        return RecViewHolder(view)
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return top.size
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = top[position]!!
        holder.bind(item)
    }
}
class RecViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    fun bind(top: FeedItem) {
        val vChannels = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_channels)
        val vViewers = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_viewers)
        val vLogo = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.item_thumb)
        val vName = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_name)

        vName.text = top.game?.name
        vChannels.text = top.channels + "chanels"
        vViewers.text = top.viewers + "Viewers"

        Picasso.get().load(top.game?.logo?.large).into(vLogo)
    }
}
```

ошибка возникает в этом моменте:

```
val feed = Feed(
                it.top.mapTo(
                    RealmList<FeedItem>(),
                    { feed -> FeedItem(feed.game, feed.channels, feed.viewers) })
            )
```

**feed.game** подчеркивается красным. Текст ошибки следующий : **Type mismatch: inferred type is FeedGameAPI but FeedGame? was expected**.
Природу ошибки я понимаю, но не знаю, как именно нужно исправить мой код, чтобы происходило корректное сохранение полученных данных и их дальнейшее использование. Прошу подскажите, кто может.
P.S Ответ приходит в подобном виде:

```
{
    "_total": 1157,
    "top": [
    {
        "channels": 953,
        "viewers": 171708,
        "game": {
            "_id": 32399,
            "box": {
                "large": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/Counter-Strike:%20Global%20Offensive-272x380.jpg",
                "medium": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/Counter-Strike:%20Global%20Offensive-136x190.jpg",
                "small": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/Counter-Strike:%20Global%20Offensive-52x72.jpg",
                "template": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/Counter-Strike:%20Global%20Offensive-{width}x{height}.jpg"
    },
            "giantbomb_id": 36113,
            "logo": {
                "large": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-logoart/Counter-Strike:%20Global%20Offensive-240x144.jpg",
                "medium": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-logoart/Counter-Strike:%20Global%20Offensive-120x72.jpg",
                "small": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-logoart/Counter-Strike:%20Global%20Offensive-60x36.jpg",
                "template": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-logoart/Counter-Strike:%20Global%20Offensive-{width}x{height}.jpg"
    },
            "name": "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive",
            "popularity": 170487
    }
    },
    ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: Наверное, вам надо вместо `feed.game` передавать `FeedGame(feed.game.name, feed.game.logo)`

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое. Немного только дополню, что исходя из моей структуры данных правильным будет: `FeedGame(feed.game.name,FeedLogo(feed.game.logo.large)`